# Closing db session if a JPA query takes too long

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

We are using JPA to persist and merge entities into an Oracle 11g db, in an application running on glassfish v3.0.1

We have been trying to close the session when a query is taking too long to finish or commit. But the session is still open in the database.

This is the thread that executes the query and tries to close everything.

```
private class PRunnable implements Runnable {

    MyEntity myEntity;

    public PRunnable(MyEntity myEntity) {
        this.myEntity = myEntity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        final EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    //It can get stuck in the merge or committing
                    em.merge(myEntity);
                    em.flush();

                    em.getTransaction().commit();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    em.getTransaction().rollback();
                } finally {

                    em.clear();
                    em.close();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(r);

        t.start();
        try {
            t.join(500);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //It's never getting here
        }

        if (t.isAlive()) {
            //If the query takes to long it successfully closes the em
            em.clear();
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

We have also tried:
(em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class).getServerSession()).disconnect();
(em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class)).close();

But the db session is always alive.

Do you know any way of successfully close the session on the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JPA 1 you should specify connection timeout in your `DataSource` configuration.

In JPA 2 (which you are using) there is a standard property: `javax.persistence.query.timeout`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I had tried: `eclipselink.jdbc.timeout`, `javax.persistence.query.timeout` and `javax.persistence.lock.timeout` but none of those seem to work. Is there any other property I can try?

Comment: @olgadg what happens? The query just continues without being timeouted?

Comment: my mistake, the time was seconds, no milliseconds. It worked. Thank you.